# Function documentation and syntax - ECMA262

Tags: javascript, v8, ecmascript-5, ecma, mathjs

Help me where I can find documentation for the `TO_NUMBER` function and what does the `%`(percentage sign) mean when placed before `MathExpRT` (which also can't find any docs about it)

https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/b0e4dce6091a8777bda80d962df76525dc6c5ea9/src/js/math.js#L62-L64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TO_NUMBER` is a V8-internal macro defined here:

https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/ac886b0c1c173d6ceff762952e1d6cf78e8bd172/src/js/macros.py#L96

Not that this will help you much: it simply calls into an intrinsic, which is implemented as generated code, and has many different implementations depending on compiler (V8 has four), hardware platform (V8 supports about 10), and available type information. One generic code generator can be seen here:

https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/5acc31d86329794407f2764a369c2f638305b376/src/code-stub-assembler.cc#L3259

If you just want to know the semantics, you better look at the ECMAScript 262 standard.

Comment: thank you very much, but ahh this code seems so intentionally obfuscated...

Comment: @MarkSpencer, it's a code generator -- for that it is actually pretty readable. ;)

Comment: what do you mean by a code generator ? like babel (which is for js)?

Comment: @MarkSpencer, a code generator producing machine code.

Comment: Isn't that a compiler?

Comment: Code generation is a part of a compiler's back-end, typically meaning machine code. What tools like Babel do is more accurately referred to as program generation.

Answer (score 0):

`%` in this context is a V8-specific syntax to denote a C++ method call, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14863721/245966) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11203238/245966) (it's *not* a JavaScript `%` which is a modulo operator).

`MathExpRT` as far as I understand from the other answers, is a name of a C++ method (in V8 runtime) to be called from within the JS file you linked.

Comment: And `TO_NUMBER` ? How can I see the source code ?

Comment: Thanks...........